# Why does OpenCV cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) only return 0?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have recently installed OpenCV for PYTHON on my mac by following the tutorial:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

I wrote a code to read a videofile, which is able to retrieve the fps,timestamp,total no. of frames, at each frame that is read:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(particle_name + video_file_type)

while True:
    time = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    total_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

    print(time, fps, total_frames)

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried this code out on Video A, .mov format, Motion JPEG Video (dmb1) codec.
And Video B, .avi format, Motion JPEG Video (MJPG) codec.

For both Video A and Video B, the fps and total_frames printed out were constants. However, for Video A, time increased gradually (as it should), but for Video B, time remained constant at 0.

I thought it could be the format of the videos that causes this difference so I changed the format of Video B to .mov while retaining the same codec, however the problem still persisted.

May I know how I can retrieve the accurate timestamp from Video B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` isn't returning the correct timestamp. This could be a codec issue. Yoo could try other codecs like XVID, MP4V, etc. Note that the extension merely denotes the container for the file and changing that may not really result in any meaningful change in the video file.

If you still are unable to get it work, use the frame count along with the FPS of the image to get the timestamp.

```
fps = cap.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_count = 0
while True:
   frame_count++
   time = float(frame_count)/fps
```

EDIT:
You can change the codec using ffmpeg. Here's a sample tutorial for Macs https://www.macxdvd.com/mac-dvd-video-converter-how-to/ffmpeg-avi-to-mp4-free.htm.